# Finding path between two nodes in a graph using BFS and DFS

Tags: graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I'm following following links.

DFS: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/DepthFirstPaths.java.html

where pathTo methods is like this

```
public Iterable<Integer> pathTo(int v) {
    validateVertex(v);
    if (!hasPathTo(v)) return null;
    Stack<Integer> path = new Stack<Integer>();
    for (int x = v; x != s; x = edgeTo[x])
        path.push(x);
    path.push(s);
    return path;
}
```

BFS: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/BreadthFirstPaths.java.html

where pathTo method is like this

```
public Iterable<Integer> pathTo(int v) {
    validateVertex(v);
    if (!hasPathTo(v)) return null;
    Stack<Integer> path = new Stack<Integer>();
    int x;
    for (x = v; distTo[x] != 0; x = edgeTo[x])
        path.push(x);
    path.push(x);
    return path;
}
```

My doubt is why `for (x = v; distTo[x] != 0; x = edgeTo[x])` is used in BFS and `for (int x = v; x != s; x = edgeTo[x])` in DFS. What will go wrong if I use `x != s` instead of `distTo[x] != 0` in BFS's pathTo method ?

Answer (score 0):

You are right in your observation, that the conditions `x != s` and `distTo[x] != 0` are interchangeable. The reason is `distTo[s]` is `0`, so loop breaks when we encounter the `source vertex`. So to break the loop when we encounter the `source vertex`, either of the two conditions will work.